# Suggestions to improve first posts reviews

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, first-post-review

I have a suggestion to improve **first posts reviews**.

I'm doing some reviews on first posts and I would appreciate that some links like **how to ask** and **on topic** to be available in the review page, so you can add them in the comments without having to look for them.

They can be placed in the section

> This is the first question asked by a new user. Help them learn to use
>   the site by reviewing their post. (more)

where there are the guidelines to help making the review. They may be *copy/paste* links, or the links themselves.

Comment: You mean magic links, that automatically expand when used in a comment? Like `[mcve]` and `[edit]` do?

Comment: You always have the help center available in the top bar, at the `?` icon.

Comment: @Xufox Yes but you have to navigate the site, maybe open a new tab, it's not about doing the work but rather handy links that are often used specifically in the reviews.

Comment: @S.L.Barth No, not neccesarely, just the links could be enough

Comment: Do you mean like the [comment formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of `[ask]` resulting in [ask] (How to ask) and `[help/on-topic]` resulting in [help/on-topic] (on-topic page)?

Comment: @Makyen Wow  I really didn't know they existed. My bad. Well I guess it's not easy to find this, I'm doing a quick search on the [help] (he, I used it here) and can't find a mention of it. This could be the answer, but still would be nice it is mentioned in the reviews message.

Comment: A list of the available shorthand links is in the "help" link that's right next to the comment input textarea. Clicking that "help" will show a short help block bellow the comment. You then need to click on "Learn more about formatting...". I agree that it should be linked from the help center. It's likely that the [Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page is linked, but it only shows the comment shorthand links if the page is opened with the [`#comment-formatting` fragment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).